# JW Player problems

Tags: jwplayer

Havin problems with the JW player on here

ferrazzilimoct dot com

Pause button doesnt seem to work, and player doesnt work in some browsers either, here is the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ferrazzilimoct.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/swfobject.js'></script>

<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced if video works</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var so = new SWFObject('http://ferrazzilimoct.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/player.swf','mpl','498','380','9');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('file','http://ferrazzilimoct.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Ferrazzi_v021.swf');
  so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its working now. Are you still having an issue?